# What are the different universes mentioned in Crisis on Infinite Earth?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash, supergirl, crossovers, batwoman

In **Supergirl** Season 5 Episode 9, which is the first episode of ***Crisis on Infinite Earths***, we see different Earths in which I can recognize *Titans* and the different Earths of Arrowverse like Earth 1, Earth 38, and Earth X.

**Edit:** There have been a lot of Earths mentioned in the other *Crisis on Infinite Earths* parts.
What are the other universes that are mentioned in the other scenes and episodes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/crisis-infinite-earths-titans-batman-movies-arrowverse-canon/) answered it pretty well:

> ## Earth 89: Tim Burton's Batman Movies
>
> Tim Burton's Batman films are represented in one quick cameo, which confirmed it as Earth-89. Danny Elfman's familiar Batman theme plays as the Bat-Signal burns bright in the red skies over Gotham City. This is observed by a man in a trench-coat and fedora, who mutters "I hope you're watching, big guy." The observer is reporter Alexander Knox (Robert Wuhl), who was the first to report upon The Joker's crimes in the 1989 Batman movie.

[image]
<sub>Alexander Knox above</sub>

> ## Earth 9: DC Universe's Titans
>
> We briefly see red skies over Titans Tower in San Francisco, before being treated to close-ups of a disturbed looking Hawk (Alan Ritchson) and an upset Jason Todd (Curran Walters).

[image][image]
<sub>Jason Todd aka Robin (Curran Walters) and Hawk (Alan Ritchson)</sub>

> ## Earth 66: 1966 Batman TV Show
>
> One of the first cameos confirmed for Crisis on Infinite Earths was Burt Ward, who played the Dick Grayson Robin on the 1966 live-action Batman series alongside Adam West's Batman. Ward's cameo is short and sweet, as we see Dick Grayson walking a dog while wearing a red sweater with yellow and green trim suggesting the classic Robin costume. Suddenly, the skies turn red and sinister, prompting the former Boy Wonder to shout "Holy Crimson Skies Of Death!" It isn't a big scene, but it is enough to confirm the 1966 Batman show as the Earth-66 of the Arrowverse.

[image] 
<sub>Dick Grayson Robin(played by Burt Ward)</sub>

Other Earth's you might already know, which are:

## Earth 1:

Flash, Arrow, and Batwoman related characters live here.

## Earth 38:

Supergirl's universe.

## Earth X:

With the Ray, evil Arrow and Supergirl, part of [older crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_on_Earth-X).

## Earth 16:

[image]

Jonathan Kent (Superman's son) landed there by mistake. And it was prominently featured before in *Legends of Tomorrow* season 1 with a dark future of Earth 1 heroes in 2046.

## Earth 2:

Mentioned by Oliver (didn't appear) which got destroyed in Arrow season 8 with a single survivor Laurel Lance.

## Unknown Earth:

[image]

Nash Wells aka Pariah belongs to this Earth, he freed the Anti-Monitor. His Earth does not appear nor is it mentioned directly or numbered yet.

Answer (score 8):

From Crisis: Episode 2 (Batwoman)

---

## Earth 74:

Legends of Tomorrow have retired and Mick Rory is left inhabiting the *Waverider*

## Earth 99:

Batman (Kevin Conroy) has retired and can only move thanks to an exoskeleton.

## Earth 75:

Superman of this Earth is killed by Lex Luthor wielding the Book of Destiny

## Earth 167:

Superman (Tom Welling) has given up his powers and is now living with his family Lois Lane (Erica Durance) and his daughter on the Kent farm.

## Earth 96:

Superman (Brandon Routh) as Clark Kent is Editor in Chief of the *Daily Planet*

## Earth 18:

Location of the Lazarus Pit. (with Jonah Hex cameo)

---

From Crisis Episode 3 (The Flash)

## Earth 203

New Gotham with the Birds of Prey

## Earth 666

Lucifer's Earth (Tom Ellis)

## Earth 90

Earth of the Flash (John Wesley Shipp)

## Earth (not stated)

Earth of Black Lightning

---

From Crisis: Episode 4 (Arrow) & Episode 5 (DC's Legends of Tomorrow)

## Earth-2

Previously destroyed, now home to the Justice Society of America & *Stargirl* (new CW series in course)

## Earth-9

Home to the the *Titans*

## Earth-12

Home to the the Green Lantern Corp - possible reference to *Green Lantern* tv series on HBO-Max

## Earth-19

Home of *The Swamp Thing*

## Earth-21

Home to *Doom Patrol*

## Earth-96 (rebooted?)

Brandon Routh is Superman

Earth-96 was inspired equally from the first five Superman movies and the classic graphic novel Kingdom Come. It was named in honor of the year in which Kingdom Come was first published - 1996.

## Earth-Prime

Previously **Earth-1**, now apparently a *combined* Earth which is home to:

- *The Flash*
- *Supergirl*
- *DC's Legends of Tomorrow*
- *Batwoman*
- *Black Lightning* - may previously have been Earth-1
- *Superman & Lois* - new CW series in course

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if instead of simply identifying actors, you would identify the show or movie.  For example: "Earth 99: 'Batman: The Animated Series' (?): Batman (Kevin Conroy) has retired and can only move thanks to an exoskeleton."

Comment: Earth 99 is not the Animated Series Earth it just features a voice actor from the show.

Comment: Ah. Okay, perhaps Earth 166 would be a better example then? To avoid pedanticism, I'll amend the suggestion to say this:  It would improve the answer to identify the significance of particular casting choices. Kevin Conroy wasn't just random casting; he is famous for playing that specific character on a particular show.  Ditto Tom Welling and Erica Durance. Ditto John Wesley Ship. Ditto Brandon Routh.  Don't get me wrong -- it's a *great* answer, and pretty thorough; I was just suggesting an improvement. Even Birds of Prey could be noted better as it was only ever a pilot episode

Comment: I'm now wondering if they tossed in a reference to the Aquaman pilot that never became a series...? ;-)

Comment: Note: The question mark in my original comment was there to indicate that it's a question as to whether that is *actually that universe*, or just a fanservice reference to that show. After all, if Conroy's Bruce Wayne walked with an exoskeleton, it also serves as a reference to Kingdom Come's Batman.  Question: is Earth 99 **definitely** not the Animated Batman universe, or just a case of "they didn't quite specify"?

Comment: @StephenR *Birds of Prey* was actually not just a pilot. It was an unaired pilot and a short season of iirc 13 episodes (including the reshot pilot [with a new Dr. Quinzel]). While watching I wondered if they used cgi for that cameo to hint at Helena's feline meta-DNA - or maybe Ashley Scott has just not aged in the intervening 15 years.